# Nodejs express API can't connect in Public works on Local

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am trying to put my application public.

I got server with nginx. Everything works fine while I am working in my local network.

There is my nginx config ( I know that there is the problem )

```
server {
        listen *:80;
        #listen [::]:80;


        access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.error.log;


        root /srv/myapp/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name myapp.mydomain.pl www.myapp.mydomain.pl;

        location / {

        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;

        #GZIP
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level    5;
        gzip_min_length  1100;
        gzip_buffers  4 32k;
        gzip_proxied       any;
        gzip_types    text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css;
        gzip_vary on;
        }
}
```

My frontend works fine but while I want for example login into app I got time out or connection refused.

How should this config looks like?

I got my front into /srv/myapp/dist and server into /srv/myapp/server

Part of my server.js

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello." });
});
```

Backend works independently but with frontend it won't

Comment: Your `nginx.conf` file describes a static web site. But you need nginx to serve as a *reverse proxy* to your nodejs app. This tutorial explains how to configure that on an Ubuntu virtual machine. It's written by DigitalOcean, but the explanation is valid elsewhere as well.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

To configre a reverse proxy, add the following to the nginx configuration.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://<ip_address>:<port>;
}
```